# How to rerender the accordion layout after inserting new element from external window

Tags: gwt, accordion, gxt

a following scenario:
1. A window with some tabs.
2. In one tab there is accordion layout and the button "Add".
3. After selecting the button "Add" a new window with a a form appears.
4. The user fills the form and select the button "Save".
5. The window with the form disappears, system adds a new record in the database with data from the form.
6. The tab re-renders the accordion layout showing old elements and the new one.

The problem is that the point 6 doesn't work. The all elements are collapsed and clicking on the title bar of any element doesn't expand the accordion. Additionally the title bars of accordions are shorter than at the first rendering.

Any help?

Regards,
Jacek

Comment: Did you try caling `forcelayout();`?